# initializing a constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class DrivingLicence

{

protected:

    Person owner;
    char * type;
    Date validity;
    int id;
    static int cid;

public:

    DrivingLicence(Person &o,char* t,Date &d);
    DrivingLicence(Person &o,char* t);
    DrivingLicence(const DrivingLicence & other);
    Date getValidity() const;
    int checkValidity() const;
    void print() const;
    bool operator== (const DrivingLicence& o) const;
    void operator +(const int num);
    const DrivingLicence& operator= (const DrivingLicence& other);
    ~DrivingLicence();
};

class Person

{

private:
    int id;
    char* name;
    Date birthday;

public:

    Person(char* name,int id1,Date &d);
    Person(const Person &other);
    ~Person();
    Date getBirthday() const;
    const Person& operator= (const Person & other);
    void print() const;
};

class Date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

public:

    Date (int day,int month,int year);
    ~Date();
    const Date& operator=(const Date& other);
    bool operator==(const Date & other);
    void print() const;
    int getYear()const;
    int getMonth()const;
    int getDay()const;
};
```

up above are my classes,
i need to initialize both constructors in the `DrivingLicence` class (not the copy cons), however i cant manage to do that.

can someone please help me with the syntax for this question??

what i mean is :

```
#include <NameOfHeaderFile>
DrivingLicense::DrivingLicense( Person &o,char* t,Date &d ) : //Code here for 1stconstructor
{

}
DrivingLicense::DrivingLicense( Person &o,char* t ) ://Code here for 2nd constructor
{

}
```

i don't know how to initialize the values

Comment: Give it a try? To me, it's totally unclear what you are having problems with.

Comment: Initialize a constructor? You don't initialize constructors... constructors initialize instances of classes (or at least they are supposed to do so).

Comment: Why are you using `char*` in C++? If this is a string, use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## include "header.h"

int DrivingLicence::cid =1000;

DrivingLicence::DrivingLicence(Person &o, char* t,  Date &d ): owner(o), type(t), validity(d)
{

}

DrivingLicence::DrivingLicence(Person &o,char* t) :owner(o), type(t),validity(8,10,2024){}

this is what i meant.
thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a header file, however usually there is only 1 class per .h file. So you need to create a file called DrivingLicence.cpp.

In this file write:

```
#include <NameOfHeaderFile>
DrivingLicense::DrivingLicense( Person &o,char* t,Date &d )
{
     //Code here for 1stconstructor
}
DrivingLicense::DrivingLicense( Person &o,char* t )
{
     //Code here for 2nd constructor
}
```

Is this what you are asking???

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem, you want a `DriverLicence` constructor that
also initializes the person inside the `DriverLicense` instance.

If so, you only have to add this overload to your class:

```
DriverLicense::DriverLicense(
    // Data for Person
    char *person_name, int person_id, Date day_birth,
    // Data for Driver licence
    char *t, Date d)
{
    owner = Person(person_name, person_id, day_birth); 



    // More code here initializing DeriverLicence members.
}
```

Remember of course add it to your class:

```
class DriverLicence
{
public:
    // ...
    DriverLicense::DriverLicense(char *, int, Date, char *t, Date d);
   // ...
}
```

*A couple of Advice:*

1. You're working with C++, use `std:string` instead `char*`
2. Don't abuse of passing arguments as references. Some times this is not
   the best to do.

Comment: i appreciate your answer ill give it try

Comment: i have tried your syntax, but still i have a compilation problem " 1 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "DrivingLicence::DrivingLicence" matches the specified type. btw i'm using char* intetionaly for practice.

Comment: An can you please show us that compilation problem?

Comment: @Theron Answer edited, the error you got if becouse you don't have added the contrutor to the class.

Comment: i can't add a constructor, i cant change the header file by definition because this is an assignment

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to initialize the members of your `DrivingLicense` class with the arguments passed to the constructor, you can do that in your initializer list.

It's would be wise to put these definitions in a cpp. Also note the changes to types and constness or the arguments I'm providing.

```
DrivingLicense::DrivingLicense(const Person &o, const std::string& t, const Date &d )
  : owner(o)
  , type(t)
  , validity(d)
{ }

DrivingLicense::DrivingLicense(const Person &o, const std::string& t)
  : owner(o)
  , type(t)
{ } // Note that 'validity' here is default constructed.
```

Comment: thank you very much that worked perfectly. i understood the problem

Comment: Glad I could help you understand.